# Extending UILocalNotification

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

I am writing a *Reminder* class that extends *UILocalNotification* class.

In its interface it has a method:

```
- (void)setType:(NSString*)type;
```

May be I am overlooking something really stupid, but when I call:

```
[reminder setType:type];
```

where *reminder* is a

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Reminder *reminder;
```

in the view controller, I do get the infamous error:

```
[UIConcreteLocalNotification setType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

It seems like *setType:* method isn't called on Reminder class but directly on UIConcreteLocalNotification, despite the fact it is declared in the interface.

Comment: If your Reminder class a subclass of UILocalNotification? Where are you setting your "reminder" property.